# SQL Server 2012 and different datatypes stored in one place

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Okay, I am not a database architect, so this question is completely coming from a software developers point of view.  I am currently working to get a simple settings database and was wondering what is the most efficient, performant way to store different types in SQL server.  For example, SettingA can have a boolean, int, float, or string value.  What is the most efficient way to store that data and the most performant to retrieve.

1. Store all types in one field that is a string and have the application server convert it to it's proper value.
2. Have different fields for different types and have the application server see which field is not null and use it (BooleanValue, StringValue, IntValue, FloatValue and have only one be non-null and with a value)
3. Normalize the settings into different tables based on types and only add value to the table if that type is used.  (Four tables BooleanValues, StringValues, IntValues, FloatValues with a foreign key to Settings table).  SP would then return whichever table has a record.

Performance is definitely my #1 concern, but space concerns would be a close second.

Comment: Will there be so many settings and so many queries that you care deeply about throughput and latency? For a settings table none of this should matter.

Comment: Would true and false be passed as "true" and "false" or "0" and "1"?

Comment: I would estimate 10 million values in the settings table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the settings in an XML column.

With that I mean all settings for an item in a single XML settings document, so that they can be retrieved and updated in one go. [Provide a schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx) to reduce the storage costs and optimize queries. The database will then know the data types of the setting values.

If you wish to query for all items with a specific value for a setting, you can use XML indices and/or XQuery queries.

I've created a SQLFiddle to show what this could look like:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49c34/1

As for the indexing, take a look at [XML Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522451.aspx) and, in particular, [Selective XML Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670108.aspx):

> The selective XML index feature lets you promote only certain paths from the XML documents to index. At index creation time, these paths are evaluated, and the nodes that they point to are shredded and stored inside a relational table in SQL Server. This feature uses an efficient mapping algorithm developed by Microsoft Research in collaboration with the SQL Server product team. This algorithm maps the XML nodes to a single relational table, and achieves exceptional performance while requiring only modest storage space.

I'd expect this to behave great, better even than using a table row per setting, if the settings are usually inserted and retrieved together. In that case it makes no sense to rip them into bits, scatter the bits into table rows, only to retrieve and glue them back again when you retrieve them.

If you wish to query for a couple specific settings, or criteria for these specific settings, selective XML indexes will help you achieve this.

When to beware:

- If settings differ wildly between items. For they will not have a shared schema and the storage needed for the settings document becomes big, possibly too big.
- If you require a wide range of queries on different elements of the settings document to perform well. For you'll probably end up needing a lot of indexing space.
- If part of the settings change more often than the rest, you may want to break those out and store them separately. For else you risk updating the entire settings document each time one single bit gets twiddled.

Comment: I don't understand why people down vote this. This could be an option and with new XQuery to query semi-constructed data, the performance could be equaly good.

Comment: Perhaps I should explain a bit more.

Comment: Yes, flup, a simple example would help a lot.  Have never used Xml indices with an XML column.  This seems overly complex and hard to work with, but I will do some testing to see if this method is as performant (or close to) a varchar column.

Comment: Added simple example without indexes plus link to msdn examples with indexes.

Comment: @flup: This seems like a great solution to store all sorts of variable data in one field.  Two questions for you and the community:

1. You really think this can perform on a similar level to what a straight varchar() column would perform at?

2. You mentioned Xml Column with Schema?  Where does the schema come in?

Comment: I'm still unsure of how you're going to use the settings. How often will they be updated? Do you need to keep track of them in time? How will you retrieve them, all at once for a single item or selectively? How different will the settings be for different items? Etc.

Comment: The schema would help reduce the storage needed for the xml document.

Comment: Updates will be rare, these settings are somewhat static.  I will be keeping an audit of updates.  I plan to cache on the app server layer, so selection will be frequent, but not overwhelming.  Server hardware isn't a big concern, as my company has great hardware resources.

Comment: Added a bit about expected performance, though admittedly the best way is to find out. I have successfully used XML columns to store large amounts of relatively static structured data.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give following suggestion, focus on high level design. 
 
First of all, looks like your system is LOB(Line of business system), not a dataware house, so, certainly if you different bussiness entity, you should normalize them follow the NF, normally, the third NF will be good enough. 
For your specific question, you have a field [SittingA], which can have 4 different possible data types, I don't think you should normalize them into different column or table, because it is only one atrribute, one filed, you don't want to add additioinal bussiness logic to control it write into different columns or tables, and when querying it, has to identify where to query. 
You can store them in one column with Varchar datatype, but create a compute column, which hash the value in your varchar column, create index on your compute column(hash index). You use store procedure to complete the hash convention and query. 
This can make your logic simple and neat. 
If you have further question or concern, please update your question or give your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #2:** 
You could do something like this with an Isnull chain to pull the information back out based upon some primary key association. Without knowing your implementation I don't know how stupid of a suggestion this would be, but it's a way to store the input on the backend in the desired format.

```
/*
        Create  Table #test 
                (
                    tID         Int Identity, 
                    StringVal   Varchar(100), 
                    FloatVal    Float, 
                    BoolVal     Bit, 
                    IntVal      Int
                )
*/

Declare @bah Varchar(100)

Set     @bah = 'ValuesToTest'

If      IsNumeric(@bah) = 0
Begin
        If      @bah In ('true','false') --Went with this assumption otherwise you'd get confused between 1 bool and 1 int
        Begin
                Insert  #test (BoolVal)
                Select  Case
                        When    @bah = 'true' Then 1
                        Else    0
                        End
        End
        Else
        Begin
                Insert  #test (StringVal)
                Select  @bah
        End
End
Else    If Floor(Convert(Money,@bah)) <> Ceiling(Convert(Money,@bah)) --Compensate for IsNumeric interpretation of money
Begin
        Insert  #test (FloatVal)
        Select  Convert(Float,Convert(Money,@bah))
End
Else
Begin
        Insert  #test (IntVal)
        Select  Convert(Int,@bah)
End
```

Your baseline for just the value columns are going to be 1 byte a piece to allow for nullable values, 1 byte for the bit column, 4 bytes for the int column, 4 bytes for the float and 2 bytes for the varchar (for the variable length storage) so it looks like you're looking at a baseline of 15 bytes.

If it's a bit or int that (15 bytes) will be your storage need, if it's a double it could go up 4 more bytes if the precision is 25 or greater and the varchar would go up a number of bytes equal to the length of the record being stored. So if you were instead to go with a non-nullable varchar it would save you a maximum of 12 bytes per record (minimum being 2 bytes for variable length storage and 1 byte for a single character value). So for 1,000,000 records you're looking at about an extra 11.5 MBs of storage for the data.

However, if you're going to be looking up primary keys based upon the values it could be faster to go with this solution because it's faster to do a lookup against a bit, int or float index value over a varchar so if when doing your look-ups you're going to know which datatype you're going after it would be faster to go this route because as long as your columns are indexed you'll be able to ignore all Nulls that have a value in a different column. If you're going to be getting values based upon primary keys go with a single varchar column because the benefit is negligible.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking.  But what does that solution do for the size of the data table?  I now have 4 fields for every value, for a table that will have millions of rows.  What if I want a 5th or 6th type.  Am I killing my storage and efficiency?

Comment: How are you going to be pulling the information? Are you going to pull a record at a time or a set? Are you going to look up primary keys based upon values or values based upon primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

With the working assumption that the database server and the application server have measurable (> 1ms) latency, I would select option 2.
There's two things at work here: data stored together in a single row is easier to query for, an quicker to access. Databases organize storage in blocks, and being in the same row (and smaller that the block size, which is typically 4KB) means faster access.

Now, you may want to set up a separate table with a Primary Key for the setting. (Fewer, smaller columns leads to faster retrieval.) Normally I'd suggest using an INT for the PK, as it allows for quick Foreign Key resolving.